# PostgreSQL - return the number of elements in one array appear in another array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a table with two columns. Each column should contain an array (`int[]`) but some are `null`.

I want to create a third column that counts how many elements of the **first** array appear in the **second** array, duplicates included.

For example,

`array_1 = {23277,23277}`

`array_2 = {23638,23187,23201,23612,28322,27953,23277,23173,23794,28796,23291,23714}`

The result is `2`. Because two (both) items of `array_1` are within `array_2`.

Similarly, if I have:

`array_1 = {23201,23612,2001,23201}`

`array_2 = {23638,23187,23201,23612,28322,27953,23277,23173,23794,28796,23291,23714}`

Result is `3` because three elements of `array_1` are in `array_2`.

Trying the `&&` operator only returns True or False.

Do I need to write a custom agg function that would unnest `array_1` and then count?

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The extension [`intarray`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html#id-1.11.7.28.6) has an intersect operator that would do that

Comment: Are you talking about the `&` operator? That returns in intersection, yes. But if you look at example one above. If I did `array_1 & array_2`, the result would be `{23277}`. Not the result I need. I am hoping for a count of the number of elements from `array_1` that are inside `array_2`.

Comment: Then you want `cardinality(array_1 & array_2)` I suppose?

Comment: Or `(select count(1) from unnest(array_1)a1(I), unnest(array_2)a2(I) where a1.i = a2.i)`

Comment: Or `(select count(1) from unnest(array_1)a1(i)  where a1.i in (select * from unnest(array_2))` ???

Comment: `(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(array_1)a1(i) WHERE a1.i in (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(array_2))` is correct :) Thank you!

Comment: Do you mind explaining `...a1(i) where a1.i...` portion? Just so that I can wrap my head around it and possibly use later in life

Comment: Just gives an alias to the result of the unnest so you can refer to it.

Comment: Right, I understand where you set `a1(i)` as the alias but I don't understand why you create an alias that contains parentheses and also don't understand how you can refer to the alias with `a1.i`...